# How do I copy text from an <Input> by using getElementbyTagName?

Tags: javascript, copy, addeventlistener, buttonclick, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to create a button that doesn't use ID to copy text from an input text field.

I thought the best way to do this would be using an event listener and then on click activate the function that would copy text from the input value.

HTML:

```
<div>
 <input type="text" value="copy this" readonly>
 <button type=button id='btn'>Copy URL</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
  <script> 
  document.querySelect('#btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
   jimsFunction();
});
  
  function jimsFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementByTagName('input').value;
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); 
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
  alert("Copied: " + copyText.value);
  }    

</script>
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First getting by `tag` is elements . You were missed `s`

```
document.getElementByTagName ->document.getElemenstByTagName
```

2. Loop elements and add event

Try it :

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
   jimsFunction(this)
});
let btns = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')
Array.from(btns).forEach(ele => {
  ele.addEventListener('click', function() {
   jimsFunction(this)
  });
})  
function jimsFunction(input) {
  let ele = input.previousElementSibling
  ele.select()
  ele.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(ele.value)
  alert("Copied: " + ele.value)
}
```

```html
<div>
 <input type="text" value="copy this" readonly>
 <button type=button id='btn'>Copy URL</button>
</div>
<div>
 <input type="text" value="text 1" readonly>
 <button type=button class='btn'>Copy URL</button>
</div>

<div>
 <input type="text" value="text 2 (different)" readonly>
 <button type=button class='btn'>Copy URL</button>
</div>
```

You are duplicate `id`, you should change to `class`

Comment: Thanks for that. Now working - albeit not exactly the result I need overall.

Comment: What I am looking for in the end is to have multiple buttons, without using ID to copy In <input> value. I've asked this below if you're able to help. Thanks

Comment: i 've edit answer for new question of you

Comment: Thankyou it works great! :D I Can see why it makes sense to use class now. I want to be able to replicate it many times - so this will be useful.